# How can I check against a cell and it's opposite cell?

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

I'm trying to check if my cells contain a specific text, and if so, if the cell opposite my 'specific text' contains another specific text.

```
A| B
1, Banana
2, Orange
3, Banana
1, Banana
```

I want to count the number of occurrences a specific text has the word banana in the cell opposite.

My thought process is something along the lines of `=IF(A:A=1,=COUNTIF(B:B,"Banana"),"")`

I'm constantly adding in new cells aswell.

I only want the count the number of times a specific text has banana next to it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you want to count occurrences of 1 in Col A and Banana in Col B?

Comment: what do you mean by 'if the cell opposite my specif text'? what is the opposite cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS() formula for matching multiple criteria in multiple ranges.

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A4,1,B1:B4,"Banana")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count the number of time a cell in column A has `1` and Column B in the same row has `Banana`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=1)*(B:B="Banana"))
```

if you are checking for a string instead of "1", make sure to put it in quotes